# Agora-RTC-React window is not defined - NEXT.js

Tags: reactjs, import, next.js, http-live-streaming, agora.io

```
import { createClient, createMicrophoneAndCameraTracks, AgoraVideoPlayer } from 'agora-rtc-react';
```

I'm getting these functions from agora-rtc-react framework. but I get the error name "window is not defined". i change the import function to [next.js #no-ssr](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import). this time I get "createClient is not a function". :(

```
TypeError: createClient is not a function

const useClient = createClient(config);
const useMicrophoneAndCameraTracks = createMicrophoneAndCameraTracks();
```

note: in this example [same app with next.js](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-RTC-React/tree/master/example/nextjs) this functions worked.

Comment: What exactly are you dynamically importing with `next/dynamic`? You should use it on your custom component, not when importing `agora-rtc-react`.